# Hello, I am getting the following error in my Flutter application. How can I resolve the problem?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/prachik/AndroidStudioProjects/singing_bowl/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'Firebase_auth'
import Firebase_auth
^
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
/Users/prachik/AndroidStudioProjects/singing_bowl/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Comment: try using command `pod install` in ios folder

Comment: First, check the pod file. Open your project in Xcode go to Pods-> Podfile
There will be a first line something like this:- "platform :ios, '9.0'". If it is commented then uncomment that line. Clean workspace and install pod.